# Upper bounds, infimum and supremum

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

I have a question about bounds and others.

So, question is that:
$D$ is the set $D = \bigl\{ \frac{(-1)^n n}{n+1}\colon n \in \Bbb{N} \bigr\}$.

How to find $\inf(D)$ and $\sup(D)$ and show they do not belong to $D$?

My approach is that:
Clearly, $1$ is an upper bound for $D$. Let $M$ be the upper bound that is less than $1$.

I know that my approach is nothing to talk about but this is all I had. Please help me.

Comment: So far so good ... can you find an element of $D$ that is greater than this hypothetical $M$?

Comment: By an informal perspective, at the end it is going to be 1, for even n's. 

However, few problems:
1) Can we say, even if informally, it is going to be 1 at the end? Because I am not sure to talk about infinity here where even and odd matters.
2) How do I do that? 
3) Checking for less elements is a good idea?

Comment: You can prove it is $1$ by considering the case that there is an $M$ that is smaller than $1$. You can then show that you can find an $n$ such that $M\lt\frac{n}{n+1}\lt 1$ which will give you a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you! I believe that I am not able to think in a mathematical way yet. Hope I can finish college guys, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.   note that the same argument for sup and inf will work, since this alternates.  The key is to realize that $\frac n {n+1}$ gets as close to 1 as you want.   The easy way to see this is to do the following rewriting:

$$\frac n {n+1}=\frac {n +1 -1} {n+1}=\frac {n+1}{n+1}-\frac 1 {n+1}=1-\frac 1 
{n+1}$$

so the positive terms get as close to 1 as you want.   The formal rule for this is called the Archimedean property of the real numbers,  for any $\epsilon>0$  we can find a natural number $n$ such that $\frac 1 n <\epsilon$.

So,  if you had an upper bound that was smaller than 1,  call it D,  we would have
$D<1$,   or $0<1-D$.  Thus,  by the Archimedean property, there is some natural number $n$ such that $\frac 1 n < 1 -D$.
Adding $D$ and subtracting $\frac 1 n$ gets us to $$D<1-\frac 1 n$$, but that contradicts $D$ being an upper bound.  (Technically we have to restrict $n$ to be even due to the alternating nature of the sequence to get the positive side, but that's no issue,  because once you have it works for one $n$, it works for all bigger $n$'s.

Can you mirror this argument for the infimum?

Comment: Thank you Alan. My answer was similar to that with the help of comments, however that is much formal! Great work.

Comment: you're quite welcome.  If this answers your question go ahead and mark the check box next to the answer to show it is closed and award a bit of reputation :)